# Android: video saved to gallery won't play

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've got a rather odd problem. I'm writing an Android application using the Xamarin framework, and I also have an iOS version of the same app also written in Xamarin. In the app the user can send photos and videos to their friends, and their friends may be on either iOS or Android. This all works fine, and videos taken on an iPhone can be played on an Android device and vice versa.

The problem I am having is when I try to programmatically save a video to the Android gallery, then that video is not able to be played in the gallery. It does appear that the video data it's self is actually copied, but the video is somehow not playable.

My videos are encoded to the mp4 format using the H.264 codec. I believe this is fully supported in Android, and like I said the videos play just fine when played via a VideoView in the app.

The code I am using to copy the videos to the gallery is below. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
public static void SaveVideoToGallery(Activity activity, String filePath) {

    // get filename from path
    int idx = filePath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    String name = filePath.Substring(idx, filePath.Length - idx);

    // set in/out files
    File inFile = new File(filePath);
    File outDir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryMovies);
    File outFile = new File(outDir, name);

    // Make sure the Pictures directory exists.
    outDir.Mkdirs();

    // save the file to disc
    InputStream iStream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
    OutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    byte[]data = new byte[iStream.Available()];
    iStream.Read();
    oStream.Write(data);
    iStream.Close();
    oStream.Close();

    // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
    // immediately available to the user.
    MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(
        activity.ApplicationContext,
        new String[] { outFile.ToString() }, 
        null,
        null);
}
```

NOTE: I know this is all in C#, but keep in mind that all the Xamarin framework does is provide an API to the native Android methods. Everything I am using is either Java or Android backed classes/functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this code snippet:

```
byte[]data = new byte[iStream.Available()];
iStream.Read();
oStream.Write(data);
```

There are a few issues here:

- You never read the files contents into the `data` buffer; [`iStream.Read()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/fileinputstream_read.htm) will only read a single byte and return it as an integer.
- `new byte[iStream.Available()]` will only allocate the amount of data bytes that are available to be read without blocking. It isn't the full file. See the docs on the [`available`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/fileinputstream_available.htm) method.
- `oStream.Write(data)` writes out a garbage block of data as nothing is ever read into it.

The end result is the outputted video file is just a block of empty data hence why the gallery cannot use it.

Fix it reading in the data from the file stream and then writing them into the output file:

```
    int bytes = 0;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    while ((bytes = iStream.Read(data)) != -1) 
    { 
        oStream.Write (data, 0, bytes);
    }
```

Full sample:

```
public static void SaveVideoToGallery(Activity activity, String filePath) {

    // get filename from path
    int idx = filePath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    String name = filePath.Substring(idx, filePath.Length - idx);

    // set in/out files
    File inFile = new File(filePath);
    File outDir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryMovies);
    File outFile = new File(outDir, name);

    // Make sure the Pictures directory exists.
    outDir.Mkdirs();

    // save the file to disc
    InputStream iStream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
    OutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

    int bytes = 0;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    while ((bytes = iStream.Read(data)) != -1) 
    { 
        oStream.Write (data, 0, bytes);
    }

    iStream.Close();
    oStream.Close();

    // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
    // immediately available to the user.
    MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(
        activity.ApplicationContext,
        new String[] { outFile.ToString() }, 
        null,
        null);
}
```

Comment: Ok yeah I was thinking that specific area was odd when I wrote it, but I was following an example from the Android documentation so just assumed it was correct. I tried that out and it works perfectly now, so thank you for the help and excellent information. One question I do have though. If the line "new byte[1024]" creates a byte array with a size of 1024 bytes, then how is it able to hold more than 1024 bytes of data? Probably a stupid question, but I am curious now.

Comment: Not a silly question at all, the 1024 is a temporary buffer that takes small chunks of the `iStream` file then appends it to `oStream`. It gets reused as many times as is needed to copy the whole file across.

Comment: Ah, I see so it takes 1024 chunks from the data for each pass until complete. Makes sense. Thanks buddy!